# Reducing loop/recursion time

Tags: python, loops, recursion, time

Hopefully I can explain this correctly without having to paste a whole wall of code in.

I have a list [0:100]. I need to find the lowest sufficient value in the list that will return a True in another function.

The trick is that I need this to be done fast! so far some of the data has taken over 65 seconds to process, due to the latter function iterating over the specific index in the list over 1000 times.

```
def search(list,grid):
    print(list)
    if len(list) <= 2:
        return list[0]
    else:
        p = len(list)//2
        print(p)
        print(list[p])
        if simulation(grid,list[p]) == 'lose':
            return search(list[p:len(list)-1],grid)
        elif simulation (grid,list[p]) == 'win':
            return search(list[0:p],grid)
```

For a certain input I need the function to return a result in less than 10 seconds. Is there anyway that I can precisely find the value I'm looking for without having to pass every single values from 0 to 100 to the function that relies on the list?

Comment: Without seeing your `simulation` function, there is not much help to be had.

Comment: You're already doing a binary search on the items from `list` (which is a bad variable name, by the way), so you only do `log(len(list))` tests using the `simulation` function. Without knowing something more about the structure of the data, or how `simulation` works, I don't think we can improve that by more than a constant factor. You could get some small improvement in the search code (avoiding slicing for instance), but that won't help much if the calls to `simulation` are the slow part.

Comment: `binary search`? `simulation(list)` is monotonic then?

Comment: agreed that you need to profile your `simulation` code. It appears to be the workhorse here. Maybe it can be cached? Look into `functools.lru_cache`

Comment: Would you like to see the full code?

Answer (score 2):

It may not be sufficient, to reach your goal, but one obvious improvement is to avoid recalculating the simulation for the same values, in case it is not a lose.

Removing all print output will speed things up too.

```
def search(seq, grid):
    if len(seq) <= 2:
        return seq[0]

    p = len(seq)//2
    sim_result = simulation(grid, seq[p])

    if sim_result == 'lose':
        return search(seq[p: len(seq)-1], grid)
    elif sim_result == 'win':
        return search(seq[0: p], grid)
```

You will probably have to look at how the simulation is run to improve further.